# Is it possible to uninstall the desktop?

Tags: desktop

I'm a Spanish student. I need to know if it's possible to uninstall the GUI meaning, make the system start and work only with the terminal, like a server. I need it for an exam in my high school tomorrow. So, if someone knows how to do it, please help me. Thank you!

---

Dont worry, I'm using a virtual machine LOL Thank you I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If You Need a Server OS**

It is possible to fully uninstall the GUI from the Terminal, but please be aware the elementary OS is not a server-targeted OS. If you need a server OS, I recommend [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). You'll get the same Debian/Ubuntu underpinnings tailored to a server environment. This is much better than trying to work backwards from a desktop-focused OS.

**If You Need a TTY Temporarily**

If you just need to access a full-screen Terminal without any GUI, you can switch to another TTY with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt/option</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> where `n` is a number 1-6.

**If You Really Are Sure You Want to Uninstall The GUI (Don't Do This)**

Please be sure you really really really want to do this. This is probably a bad idea. It might be hard to recover. If you're 100% sure, open up a Terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg
```

That should uninstall the X server (the thing that lets us display graphics). Please don't do this unless you are 100% sure this is what you want.

Comment: Dont worry, I'm using a virtual machine LOL Thank you I'm going to try it.